# Displaying a view with a title

Tags: php, url-routing

I want to display a view and pass parameters to it.

Here is all the code:

**Router.php**:

```
class Router {

    public function __construct() {
        if(!$this->urlController) {
            require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/View.php';
            $viewClass = new View();
            $viewClass->render('index', 'This is just the title of the page.');
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make a `View` class that displays the page "index" and where I can set the title of the page or pass parameters to it by using `$viewClass->render('index', 'This is just the title of the page.');`?

Comment: Ya know, your router really should not be responsible for rendering templates (even if you want to pretend that this template is a "view").

Answer (score 0):

i got it. here is my answer:

class Router {

```
    public function __construct() {
        if(!$this->urlController) {
            require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/View.php';
            $viewClass = new View();
            $viewClass->setTitleForPage('Title of Page');
            $viewClass->render('index', 'This is just the title of the page.');
        }
    }
}
```

then just pass the variable you got from `setTitleForPage` to the `render` function in the `View` class and then you can do something like this: `require '/view/YourPage.php'` and to the get the variable in the page, you can do this: `$this->pageTitle`. Good luck!